# What is the difference between statistical distribution and random distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random

Sorry for the stupid question, I am confused about the two concept due to the definition of random distribtion on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomDistribution.html).

It says: A statistical distribution in which the variates occur with probabilities asymptotically matching their "true" underlying statistical distribution is said to be random.

According to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StatisticalDistribution.html), statistical distribution is: "The distribution of a variable is a description of the relative numbers of times each possible outcome will occur in a number of trials."

Doesn't it mean that both concept are equivalent? Would would be a statistical distribution which is NOT a random distribution?

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Best to rely on textbooks and lecture notes from university courses for definitions and explanations of concepts in statistics and probability.

Comment: I do not have university courses specifically such concept. The term shows up in a relatively unrelated course describing an issue, so I want to be sure of it.

Comment: As far as I know the terms 'statistical distribution' and 'random distribution' can have various meanings in different contexts. (Sometimes a statistical distribution might refer to a distribution such as Student's t distribution or the variance ratio distribution F often used in statistical inference.) If you can say specifically what your difficulty is, maybe someone can help. But I have no idea what the authors of the Wolfram links are talking about. So when the problem is posed only in terms of those links, I can't be of any help at all. Lack of activity may indicate others also puzzled.

Comment: I see. It seems that my question is not relevant for me anyway.